# Static vs dynamic type-checking in a large SPA frontend?

Tags: javascript, types, typescript

If I want to use static type-checking, I need to choose some of the existing solutions like Flow or TypeScript. Then I need to align my code to the offered rules. The advantage is I have instant error highlights in the IDE, fail quick and early, as well as these are powerful and mature tools.

If I want to do dynamic checking, I need to build my own tools that will run inside the app on each method call where I need to be sure it receives correct input parameters. The advantage is that I have full control on my code and I don't have to follow the others' rules if I don't like them. The disadvantage is it can be time-consuming to develop and test it and slow in action, as well as I can make conceptual mistakes that will force me to spend time not on the logic of the app but on improving my home-grown schema-checker system.

Which approach should I use if I plan that the app will be developed by a team and have a long lifecycle?

Answer (score 1):

> Which approach should I use if I plan that the app will be developed by a team and have a long lifecycle?

A lot goes into creating tools. I'm personally leveraging all the effort already put in by the TypeScript team into creating something that exposes its full power in the form of [alm](http://alm.tools/) IDE.

Where you draw the line between using whats there and creating something new is your choice. I just like the [consolidation](https://medium.com/@basarat/typescript-won-a4e0dfde4b08) and went full in with TypeScript.